# Is static a modifier in C++?

Tags: c++, standards, definition

I've always thought of 'modifiers' in C++ as adjectives for a type (non-technical, easy to remember definition for myself). Strictly for the purposes of communication, would it be appropriate to refer to 'static' as a modifier?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I do understand what static is and does, I just want to know technically how to communicate what type of symbol/keyword/etc it is in a discussion. The standard doesn't seem to pin an exact tag on it, although I only searched through it briefly.

Comment: Its a **storage class** . Defines scope and lifetime. But i think it is closer to a **qualifier** .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would have used the term: storage-class-specifier:

7.1.1 Storage class specifiers [dcl.stc]

```
storage-class-specifier:
             register
             static
             thread_local
             extern
             mutable
```

But in normal conversations the term "Modifier" is acceptable.

Comment: Aren't those a subset of modifiers?

Comment: @RobertDailey: The trouble is that "Modifers" is not a term used by the standard. So it is OK for casual usage as people will get what you are saying but if you want to get technical no.

Answer (score 5):

There are **modifiers** , **type qualifiers**  and **storage classes** :

Storage Classes:

- auto
- register
- static   <---------you are here!(if you ask my opinion, it is between qualifier and storage)
- extern
- mutable
- Thread-local<-----(i learned this just now :D  Thx Loki Astari)

Type qualifiers:

- const
- volatile
- restrict
- __align <------- Not sure(it says IBM)

Modifier Types:

- Signed
- Unsigned
- Long
- Short
- Class access: public
- Class access: private
- Class access: protected

Also 'mutator functions' are intercepted as modifiers but i dont know if it is legal.

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

`static` is a modifier that does have an effect on the code. Therefore it is appropriate to communicate it.

The two uses of `static` I know are for static methods and to make data file local.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a modifier - althought it might have slightly different meaning when applied to variables, functions, methods etc. [Read here for further information.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html)